# How To Calibrate MacBook Pro with Epson 4880 Stylus Pro

Tags: printer, macbook, calibration

I would like to know how to calibrate my MacBookPro with my Epson 4880 Stylus Pro.  In other words how to make the colours I see on my computer screen print out with the same colours on my Epson.

I have the latest edition of Adobe. I have researched calibration, but just can't seem to get the hang of it.  It is close, but still off.

Answer (score 1):

To calibrate your MacBook Pro correctly you need to have access to a calibration tool such as an X-Rite EyeOne.  Using a tool such as this and its software allows you to create a calibration table which you can then apply to your graphics card as well as use in Adobe products.  To match correctly you should also calibrate your Epson Stylus using this tool, this will give you a consistent calibration with the computer calibration.

However in saying this to correctly have a screen calibrated you really need to have a particular external monitor with a hood and specific lighting.  The simplest method to colour accuracy is calibrate the printer the best you can, and use PMS colours.  Your printer hopefully has access to Pantone tables and should be able reproduce these consistently.

Comment: Keep in mind that the printer will have a different colour gamut from the monitor. In other words, some monitor colours are not printable, and the printer may have some colours that the monitor cannot display. Also, Pantone colours are only correct if Pantone inks are used. These are not available for inkjet printers.